# TinyMCE buttons broken

Tags: admin, tinymce, editor, dashboard

For some reason my TinyMCE buttons are completely misaligned and have the wrong `background-position` (See image below):

[image]

I have attempted to download a fresh install of Wordpress 3.5 and replaced my files with the following from it:

```
/wp-includes/css/editor.min.css
/wp-includes/images/wpicons.png
```

However nothing changed. I haven't edited the admin stylesheet either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** It appears chrome had a corrupt cache as I attempted to visit the backend on Firefox and noticed that the issue wasn't there.

I had to delete all Chrome browsing data (cache alone wouldn't do it).